# Default enumerable if empty in one go?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

You have simple extension signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DefaultEnumerableIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<T> defaultEnumerable)
```

It returns defaultEnumerable if initial collection is null or empty. Default enumerable could be null, empty or non-empty (in other words it can be any value you desire).
Theres is the question: how to implement it to run in one go? Is this possible?

I came up with this solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DefaultEnumerableIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<T> defaultEnumerable)
{
    if (enumerable != null)
    {
        var enumer = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        if (enumer.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return enumer.Current;
            while (enumer.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return enumer.Current;
            }
            yield break;
        }
    }
    return defaultEnumerable;//of course this will fail to compile
}
```

It will fail to compile, of course. So, that's a problem.

Comment: Hard to tell by your code what's the real intention behind it. You need to add more details

Comment: I don't know what more you need. This is simple extension with childish logic.

Comment: Changing `return defaultEnumerable` to `foreach (var item in defaultEnumerable) yield return item;` should do the trick.

Comment: No, this will NOT do the trick, cause defaultEnumerable is nullable. Im tired to mention it every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following two critical requirements:

- No enumerable should be iterated more than once.
- The function should return `null` (not an empty enumerable) if the original enumerable is null or empty, and the `defaultEnumerable` is `null`.

It is not possible to fulfill both requirements at the same time and staying completely lazy. To prove this, let’s assume a non-null `enumerable` (the `null` case could be easily handled separately and is no problem).

In order to know whether an enumerable is empty, we need to peek at it, i.e. try to get the first element. Since this starts the enumeration of the enumerable, we need to complete it in order to avoid enumerating it multiple times.

Since this is logic that needs to be executed, the underlying enumerator needs to exist (so it can execute that code, and attempt to peek at the original enumerable). In order for that enumerator to exist, there must be an actual object that this is encapsulated in: An enumerable. So having this logic prevents us from being able to return `null`.

The only way this would be possible is by executing the logic early. A simple solution would be to read the whole enumerable into memory first:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DefaultEnumerableIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<T> defaultEnumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null)
        return defaultEnumerable;

    List<T> items = enumerable.ToList(); // enumerate it once
    if (items.Count == 0)
        return defaultEnumerable;
    return items;
}
```

You could also retrieve the enumerator to read the first element immediately and to evaluate the logic, and then reconstruct an enumerable from that enumerator:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DefaultEnumerableIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<T> defaultEnumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null)
        return defaultEnumerable;

    var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        return CombineBack(enumerator);

    return defaultEnumerable;
}

private static IEnumerable<T> CombineBack<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
{
    yield return enumerator.Current;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        yield return enumerator.Current;
}
```

Note that this actually starts iterating the original enumerable *immediately*. It is not completely lazy like you would expect from enumerables and generator functions. You only get the laziness after the first element.

---

If you relax your restrictions, you have two options. If you accept peeking at the enumerable once, you could add a simple check using `Enumerable.Any()`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DefaultEnumerableIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<T> defaultEnumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any())
        return defaultEnumerable;
    return enumerable;
}
```

Alternatively, if you accept returning an empty enumerable instead of `null`, you could make a generator that attempts to iterate over the enumerable and yields from it, falling back to the default enumerable if there were no values in the original enumerable. This will always return a non-null enumerable though:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DefaultEnumerableIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<T> defaultEnumerable)
{
    bool didYield = false;
    if (enumerable != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            didYield = true;
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    if (!didYield && defaultEnumerable != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in defaultEnumerable)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will throw exception if defaultEnumerable is null. So, no, this doesn't count.

Comment: Nice :) you just changed to `.Any()` a moment before I did

Comment: @eocron06 Your question did not state anything about `defaultEnumerable` possibly being null. But added fallbacks for that case.

Comment: Quotation: 'It returns defaultEnumerable if initial collection is null or empty' What else do I need to say? You don't have right to change defaultEnumerable, you just need to pass it's value.

Comment: @eocron06 Which does not say anything about the case when `defaultEnumerable` is null…

Comment: You just need to pass it's value. Isn't this obvious?

Comment: Nitpicking: you could save an allocation by explicitly null checking instead of enumerating `Enumerable.Empty<T>`

Comment: Just checked the BCL source code, actually you would save nothing they've already optimized this corner case. Sweet.

Comment: @KooKiz Oh really? I was just being lazy here, but that’s awesome :D

Comment: @poke Well, the first time for a given `T` you get the allocation, but it's cached for further calls

Comment: Guys, this still doesn't work. Let's talk about performance after we solve this ))

Comment: @eocron06 You cannot return `null` from a generator function. Also “still doesn’t work” is hardly accurate. It doesn’t fit your amended requirements, but that’s all. The function as it is returns *a default enumerable* as a fallback. That seems to be a good solution given its name.

Comment: There is varibale provided. With exact same name. And question provided with everything in it. So if it's not possible - that's the right answer. Why to provide solutions that doesn't answer the question?

Comment: Well, it is possible, you just have to avoid using generators, or wrap the generator function in another function. But at this point it becomes somewhat complicated and impractical to maintain your “only iterate it once” requirement. That being said, the original function using `Any()` can return `null` properly. It will just peek once at your original enumerable.

Comment: This why I asked such stupid question, just to know if it's possible to combine generator and value into another generator in one go in this particular case.

Comment: @eocron06 Had some more thoughts on this and expanded my answer.